# GNU GRUB version 2.02-beta2-9 showing after installation

Tags: system-installation

I installed elementary OS alongside windows  using a USB drive onto an external hard drive (transcend)  and after installation it shows this GRUB command line.

I can't even boot into Windows and I'm using an hp laptop with UEFI firmware and I don't know my group partition number and I have never installed Linux before, so I would need step by step instructions.

Comment: Please someone help me. My exams are coming and I need my laptop 

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Nevermind I fixed it. This website sucks.